# usage of glutMainloop() and the other functions in OpenGL

Tags: opengl

I am really confused about glutMainloop() function. Which functions are used in this function's loop? I thought  glutIdleFunc() is used, but I've seen codes which don't use this function.

```
#include <GL/glut.h>

static void RenderSceneCB()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

static void InitializeGlutCallbacks()
{
    glutDisplayFunc(RenderSceneCB);
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE|GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowSize(1024, 768);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutCreateWindow("Tutorial 01");

    InitializeGlutCallbacks();

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

Also in this code why InitializeGlutCallbacks() is used? Why not just glutDisplayFunc(RenderSceneCB); written instead of InitializeGlutCallbacks()?
Lastly why is InitializeGlutCallbacks() static?

Comment: Functions starting with `glut` aren't part of the OpenGL; they are parts of `glut` library instead (it can be FreeGLUT or whatever).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only callback (a function that gets called whenever something happens) you really need is glutDisplayFunc, which is called when you need to write what the application is going to display (this is usually done around 60 times per second, but depends on a number of things, such as computer performance or vertical sync).

glutIdleFunc is a function that gets called whenever there is nothing else to do (that's why it's idle), but it is not necessary. This function will be needed depending on the way you're designing your application but, as you can see on the above program, mainly optional.

As to why it's calling InitializeGlutCallbacks(), this is what we can call "good programming practices": again, not necessary, but you would do good in gathering all your initialization functions inside a function so it helps when reading the code.

Lastly, I don't see absolutely any reason of why one would make those functions static other than preventing other modules to access them. You can try deleting the "static" and you'll see it works all the same.

edit: Explained as I'm guessing you are somehow forced to use glut, but I agree with other posters, GLFW is a better option if you can choose.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I understand which functions are used by glutmainloop()? For example; http://codepad.org/ZcXbabk9
 glutReshapeFunc(ChangeSize);
 glutDisplayFunc(RenderScene);
        glutSpecialFunc(SpecialKeys);
these three functions are used in glutmainloop() I guess.

Comment: If you mean what callbacks it uses, there's a full list here: http://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/glut/spec3/node45.html

Comment: And, just as a personal guess, here is a list I recommend you to look at: glutKeyboardFunc, glutMouseFunc, glutMotionFunc, glutPassiveMotionFunc and glutTimerFunc. This will probably get you on your track (tho the others are useful as well, of course)

Comment: Thanks and I guess the functions which use these functions also called right?

Comment: Yes, the functions you provide will get called once they have to. For example, gutKeyboardFunc(keyb) being keyb "void keyb(unsigned char key, int x, int y);", will make "keyb" get called whenever user presses a key.

Comment: no noi I said  like InitializeGlutCallbacks(). It uses one of these functions in the list and it is called.

Comment: ah yes, you should put these in InitializeGlutCallbacks() to keep everything tidy